# emacs encoding per filetype

Tags: emacs, character-encoding

Is it possible to set the language-environment only for files with a certain file extension?

I would like to set python-files (.py) to utf-8 and leave the other files untouched (win-1252).

Currently, I set:

```
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
```

Which affects all files.

Comment: If you use a templating system  (e.g. [auto-insert](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode) ) to initialize your python file, you can add the setting in the template: `#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
`

Comment: The reason for this request, is, that elpy cannot deal with windows encoding. Setting the encoding in the .py did not resolve that problem. But nice idea, thanks!